# YouTube video Stops

Tags: video, download, streaming, youtube

Whenever I'm watching a YouTube video the downstream just stops at a random point (normally at the middle of the video), and whatever I try to do (reload the page, clean cache) I just can't watch the video past that point.

I've Googled a bit and [seems that I'm not alone](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/youtube/thread?tid=36d75904c9f96906&hl=en), does anyone know how to fix this?

I'm using **Windows 7 Build 7100**, **Firefox 3.5.5** with **Adobe Flash Player 10** and I've a 24Mbps ADSL connection, in Portugal.

Comment: Try the beta flash viewer http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/ It's also super helpful if you include your OS (and version), and any thing else that might be of interest (say, version of flash)

Comment: I have the same issue using ubuntu 9.10 in firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling Adobe Flash and reinstall the [Flash 10.1 beta](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10). Also, reset the router or modem and make sure than you're not maxing out either your the routing table with torrents or your bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try installing [Google Chrome](http://www.google.it/chrome), but it could be useful to know what Operating System you're running (Windows Xp/Vista/7, Gnu/Linux of what flavour, MacOS 9.2/X, etc ?)

Best regards

EDIT: while you're waiting for some REAL solution, you could be interested in this: http://www.kissyoutube.com/
When you are watching a video with the behaviour you've reported in your answer, add "kiss" to the URL

Comment: I have the same problem on Chrome sometimes

Comment: I really doubt it's a Firefox problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check it on another browser, IE, Opera etc...... or you may try installing the flash (Active X and Player) and shock wave player as well ??